# Placing Nivo-Slider Loading Screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have Nivo-Slider up and running on my site. It works great after loading - but while loading, it is placed in the top left side of my screen. After loading - it goes to where I've directed it to go in CSS. I'm trying to figure out the CSS container for the loading screen, but I'm not sure where to start.

Image of Loading problem:
http://i46.tinypic.com/szdg7s.jpg

What I'd like the loading function to look like in my layout:
http://i50.tinypic.com/uyfyb.jpg

My Nivo Code in Index:

```
<!--/ Run Nivo-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: 15, // For slice animations
        boxCols: 8, // For box animations
        boxRows: 4, // For box animations
        animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: true, // Next & Prev navigation
        directionNavHide: true, // Only show on hover
        controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        controlNavThumbsFromRel: false, // Use image rel for thumbs
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', // Replace this with...
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', // ...this in thumb Image src
        keyboardNav: true, // Use left & right arrows
        pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
        captionOpacity: 0.8, // Universal caption opacity
        prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
        randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
        beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
        afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>




 <!--/ Show Nivo--> 

<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="/dev/images/scs-logo.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="/dev/images/signage.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="/dev/images/wsop.jpg" alt="" />

</div>
```

CSS Code that places the Nivo Slideshow after it loads:

```
/*Nivo-Slider Div*/

#slider {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

Comment: Try remove the position:absolute line

Comment: remove position:absolute, add position:relative; please post link

Comment: ^ You two nailed it, works great now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't add `#slider` to the `.nivoSlider` class in the CSS.  That was how I fixed the positioning issue I was having.  I had added `#slider` to the `.nivoSlider` class in the CSS and what it did was carry my slide over to the upper left hand side of the screen. :\

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#slider { margin:0 auto; float:left; width:100%; }
```